# How can I make a large code block hidden until selected by a reviewer in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops

Reviewing a pull request, I reflowed a relatively large JSON-like block that would be best hidden until expanded by the author.

This is *apparently* possible via [HTML support for `<details><summary>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_summary.asp), but [the relevant ticket I found](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/5433) provides a positive, yet unhelpful message

> There is no documentation explicitly for HTML syntaxes.

What should I use to make a very large code block hidden (but toggleable) by reviewers in Azure Devops Markdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [latest docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops#html-tag-support-in-wiki-pages), there is indeed a trick, which is to put a blank line after the HTML element to allow nested markdown, and otherwise use a `<details><summary>` tag normally

````
<details>
<summary>
Code Block Title
</summary>
<p>

```python
large_helpful_dict = {
    "complex JSON-like object": {
        "with nested keys": "and values"
    }
}
```
</p>
</details>
````

[meta]: to get this on SO without ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ, use a 4 spaces-style code block